# Pricing plans and custom discounts for some users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have `User`s and `Plan`s in my app.

We want to create custom discounts on a user per user basis.

I thought that my `SpecialDiscount` model should `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :plan` (so it's a Join Model), and in this model we'd have the `discounted_price`.

How to display the plans in a pricing page, along with the special price that user might have?

One simple way to do it would be like this:

```
# Controller
@plans = Plan.all
@user_special_discounts = current_user.special_discounts # They might no exist, since special discounts are optional

# In view.html.erb

<% @plans.each do |plan| %>

    This plan price is <%= plan.price %>

    <% if discount = @user_special_discounts.select {|discount| discount.plan == plan } %>

        You have a discount on this plan: <%= discount.discounted_price %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Is this a good approach or is there a more rails-idiomatic way of doing it, maybe using ActiveRecord .select ?

Comment: Will the user always have just one discount, or will he or she have multiple discounts to choose from?

Answer (score 1):

I would define a method on the User model that would return the special discounts for a given plan.  so

```
def special_discount_for(plan)
  special_discounts.select {|discount| discount.plan == plan }
end
```

Typically it is not idiomatic to have more than one instance variable per view.  Additionally it is usually bad practice to have logic in the view(eg: @user_special_discounts.select {|discount| discount.plan == plan } ).  If you had 10 places that need to display special_discounts and you needed to change the implementation you would need to make 10 changes your way.  By putting it in the model you avoid the need to make multiple changes.